# How can I plot a vector in simulink?

Tags: matlab, plot, simulink, matrix-multiplication

[Matrix Multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ALPH.jpg)

I have a matrix 6 * 6 and a vector 1 * 6 so the multiplication will give us a vector dimention 1*6 (as shown in the image above) and I have no experience with simulink and don't know how to do the multiplication and plotting the resulting vector ( which is the most important part ).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is there a reason why you would like to do that in simulink instead of matlab?

Comment: I was asked to do this using simulink also this is only a part of the whole study yet I was stuck at the beginning. If it is not possible using simulink then matlab will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing this:
[image: model]

- use constants block for defining the matrices
  [image: matrix]
- use product block for multiplication with these parameters
  [image: product]

Comment: Thank you I managed to get the results of the multiplication and now how can I plot the results?

Comment: it really depends on what you want. 
If you need to plot them against the simulation time, the  **scope block** is what you need. 
Else if you need to plot it against another vector, the quickest solution i can think of is to use a **matlab function block**  with this code inside:  
    `function vecPlot(x,y)  
    %#codegen  
    coder.extrinsic('plot')  
    plot(x,y)  
    end`

Comment: Yes I want to plot it against time, I used the scope block like you said but what I got is 6 vertical lines where lines represents the values of the final vector, is there a solution to this?

Comment: it's not really clear what you want from the description then. Try to use the **array plot** block, then double click the block, under >plot>settings change plot type to line. This will show you the array points connected similarly to matlab plot instead of the array points on their own

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get the final plot.